# Use wp_ajax_ action only after plugin loaded

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I use add_action('wp_ajax_loadcalendar_dates', 'loadcalendar_dates'); to load a custom ajax function. The thing is i also use polylang plugin for translation witch isn't ready loaded when the wp_ajax action hook is called.  Does it exist any posibility load wp_ajax only after all the plugins are loaded?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_ajax_functions' ); 

function load_ajax_functions() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_loadcalendar_dates', 'loadcalendar_dates');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadcalendar_dates', 'loadcalendar_dates');

        function loadcalendar_dates(){
            ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it seems it was a polylang issue i had to pass also pll_load_front: 1 as parameter from js to php.